# How do I access my Activity Dashboard from a personal account on Google Slides?

Tags: google-slides

I have a personal Google Slides presentation that is shared with a small number of people.

I want to check the **View History** of the presentation but can't find a way:

1. There was no **Activity Dashboard** link in the **Tools** menu, as described in [How To See The View History Of Google Docs, Sheets & Slides](https://usingtechnologybetter.com/blog/how-to-see-the-view-history-of-google-docs-sheets-slides/).
2. The **Activity Dashboard** button
   [image: Activity Dashboard button] described by Google in [Now your Activity Dashboard is one click away](https://workspaceupdates.googleblog.com/2018/11/now-your-activity-dashboard-is-one_13.html) was completely missing from the top of the page.

The two options above seem to apply Google accounts for Work or School, but not Personal accounts.

How do I access the **Activity Dashboard** from a personal Google account?

Answer (score 1):

The Activity Dashboard is only available when you are using a work or school account.

When you are using a personal `@gmail.com` account, you can only view *edits*. See **File > Version history**.

- Google Support: [Find what's changed in a file](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/190843)